# how to join tuple datetime

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, datetime

I'm new with Python and trying to add some data from an Oracle table to an array and add another value as datetime (string) for record.

My code is:

```
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pass', dsn_tns)
q='SELECT columns FROM table'

device_status = []
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(q)
results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    device_status.append(row + tuple(now))

con.close()
print device_status[1]
```

This is the output:

```
('1110', '1000074', 2060, '2', '0', '1', '7', '-', '0', '2', '-', '2', '3', ' ', '1', '1', ':', '5', '2', ':', '0', '2')
```

I want to join the date so the output will look like:

```
('1110', '1000074', 2060,'2017-02-23 11:57:41')
```

Tried to use join but got the following error:

```
can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change,

```
for row in Results:
    device_status.append(row + (now,))
                                   ^
```

`,` this make which as a tuple. So both are become tuple.

And `tuple(now)` will split all the values like this,

```
In [42]: a = '2017-02-23 11:57:41'
In [43]: print tuple(a)
('2', '0', '1', '7', '-', '0', '2', '-', '2', '3', ' ', '1', '1', ':', '5', '7', ':', '4', '1')
```

See the working,

```
In [34]: time_
Out[34]: '2017-02-23 15:33:42.353505'
In [35]: (1,2,45.7,799)+(time_,)
Out[35]: (1, 2, 45.7, 799, '2017-02-23 15:33:42.353505')


In [36]: (1,2,45.7,799)+(time_)  # tried with out , and gets an error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-551a4c2dc8d7> in <module>()
----> 1 (1,2,45.7,799)+(time_)

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited: I learned you can access tuple elements by index. You could do something like this:

```
>>> a
('1110', '1000074', 2060, '2', '0', '1', '7', '-', '0', '2', '-', '2', '3', ' ', '1', '1', ':', '5', '2', ':', '0', '2')
>>> print(a[0], a[1], a[2], (''.join(a[3:])))
('1110', '1000074', 2060, '2017-02-23 11:52:02')
```

You could then append this value to the `device_status` list.

This relies on the first 3 values always being of the type you're looking for and from index 3 onwards being a date and time value. Hope this helps.